# Replace list of words with other words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below list of words I wish to replace with another word, and wish it to be case insensitive.

For instance, `101 North First   Avenue.` should become `101 n 1st ave`.

How is this best accomplished?

```
var o={
    'first':'1st',
    'second':'2nd',
    'third':'3rd',
    'forth':'4th',
    'fifth':'5th',
    'sixth':'6th',
    'seventh':'7th',
    'eighth':'8th',
    'nineth':'9th',
    'tenth':'10th',
    'north':'n',
    'south':'s',
    'east':'e',
    'west':'w',
    'avenue':'ave',
    'street':'st',
    'place':'pl',
    '  ':' ',
    ',':'',
    '.':''
}
```

Comment: Take care when setting up your test cases in a situation like this to include examples like `"101 Northwoods Lane Northeast Second Floor"` and `"201 Wadforth Street"`. These sort of test cases make the answer from @zvona look even more appealing as the split is going to prevent output like `"201 Wad4th st"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"101 North First   Avenue.".split(" ").map(function(key) {
    return o[key.toLowerCase().replace(/\.|\,/g,"")] || key
}).join(" ");
```

Would return:
**"101 n 1st   ave"**

Comment: Thanks Zvona,  Interesting approach.  Let me try it out.

Comment: I made a quick perf test against other (working) examples: http://jsperf.com/map-vs-replace

Comment: Thanks for the perf test.  Note that it won't replace commas and periods: http://jsfiddle.net/G62cL/

Comment: @user1032531: so how did you solve the issue with the commas and periods which do not have a space in front using the accepted answer?

Comment: I made a fix for the example to ignore dots and commas. Feel free to add any other special characters to the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Str;   
 function replace(Str)
    {
      for(var i=0;i<o.length,i++)
      {
         var key = o[i].key
          str= str.replace(key,o[i].key );
      }
      return Str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
function replacer(str) {
    var pairs = {
            'first': '1st',
            'second': '2nd',
            'third': '3rd',
            'forth': '4th',
            'fifth': '5th',
            'sixth': '6th',
            'seventh': '7th',
            'eighth': '8th',
            'nineth': '9th',
            'tenth': '10th',
            'north': 'n',
            'south': 's',
            'east': 'e',
            'west': 'w',
            'avenue': 'ave',
            'street': 'st',
            'place': 'pl',
            '  ': ' ',
            ',': '',
            '.': ''
    };
    Object.keys(pairs).forEach(function (key) {
        str = str.split(key).join(pairs[key]).split(switchCase(key)).join(pairs[key]);
    });
    return str;
}

function switchCase(word) {
    if (word[0].toUpperCase() == word[0]) {
        return word[0].toLowerCase() + word.slice(1);
    } else {
        return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/ykyUu/1/)